# Why HTML body tag is not containing the whole document?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML document, when I select the BODY tag in Chrome inspect, some little space is left out on top which is I suppose part of HTML document.

[Image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTKXu.png)

But when I go inside in the BODY tag's DIV, it's like this

[Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hukbG.png)

My question is why body tag is not covering the whole document, I think BODY includes everything in a HTML document. Why is some little space is left out?

Comment: Margin collapsing. Because of it, the div's margin technically extends past the body's size.

Comment: When I select the HTML tag everything gets selected, I'm not able to upload that image because of Stackoverflow restrictions on new user.

Comment: Can you update your question with CSS code ? Based on that we will be able to we will able to help you

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

Because most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.

If you want to change it, you can just do this, add it on your css

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Want to be more complete?

use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `html,body` instead of `*` for this specific problem? Otherwise you'll be overwriting the default padding/margin on other tags which might not be intended.

Answer (score 0):

The container margin is the reason for this. Look at the CSS code for the div. It should look something like this

[image: Container CSS]

Change the margin (or just the margin-top property) to 0 and it should adjust to the top.

Hint: Chrome uses that orange border to indicate, that this is a margin.

Edit: Like another answer supposes, this is probably not caused by the container, but by the body itself. You should then assign a `margin: 0` to the body instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

you should style your body like this

```
 body{
padding:0;
 margin:0; 
}
```

it will remove the free space in all four sides